# What's the use of these packages if none of them contain exe file?

Tags: openvpn

I extracted these 3 files from [here](https://openvpn.net/community-downloads/). 
SOURCE TARBALL (GZIP), SOURCE TARBALL (XZ), SOURCE ZIP. None of them contain exe file.

What's the use of these packages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They contain the Source code for the executable, so you can edit it and compile your own special version, or audit the code.

OpenVPN software is released as [Open Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source_software), so that's literally the source (sitting out there in the open).

if you want to just install the software, you can download one of the installers if you use windows, or lookup how to install OpenVPN on your desired platform.